# An integral related to QFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, integration

How to show $$\displaystyle\int\int\int f(p,p')e^{ip\cdot x-ip'\cdot x}d^3pd^3p'd^3x=(2\pi)^3\int f(p,p)d^3p$$  ?

I have $p\cdot x=Et-\bf p\cdot x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, following the suggestion of Olaf and Vladimir,
assume that the momenta are on-shell, so that $E = E(p)$.
Then we first do the position integral to get a delta function
which lets us perform one of the momentum integrals:
$$\begin{align}
\int d^3p\,d^3p'\,d^3x\   f(p,p')e^{ip\cdot x-ip'\cdot x}
&=\int d^3p\,d^3p'\,d^3x\  f(p,p')e^{i(E(p)-E(p'))t - i(\vec p - \vec p')\cdot\vec x}\\
&=(2\pi)^3\int d^3p\,d^3p'\  f(p,p')e^{i(E(p)-E(p'))t}\delta^{(3)}(\vec p - \vec p')\\
&=(2\pi)^3\int d^3p \  f(p,p)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that $x\cdot p$ is not just the ordinary 3D dot product? T

Because in this case you can use the property of the delta function,

$$\int  e^{i(p-p')\cdot x}  d^3x = (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(p-p')$$

which you can use to integrate out $p'$.

Comment: Olaf, $p\cdot x$ can be $Et-\vec{p}\vec{x}$: after integrating over $d^3x$ the energies $E'(\vec{p}')=E(\vec{p})$, so their difference vanishes.